# Commerce 2: Can a product buyer set the price they want to pay for a product during checkout?

Tags: 8, commerce

I want to create a product where users can enter the price they'd like to pay for it. How can I do it?

Edit: Just changed the question to be a little more clear. I will be trying the solution posted by Ismail for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This module https://github.com/bojanz/donation_example can be a good start. There it is donation, but you can customize it to serve your purpose.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_choose_price is probably the best option.